# {get;set;} test class

Tags: unit-test

How do i get coverage for this type of {get;set;}?

Apex class:

```
public Boolean viewMode {get;set;}
     public Boolean editMode {get;set;}
      public Boolean hasError {
        get {
            if(hasError == null)
                hasError = false;
            return hasError;
        }
        set;        
    }
```

Test Method:

```
   apvc.viewMode =true;
   apvc.editMode =true;
   apvA.hasError=null;
```

[image]

I get the following error

```
System.AssertException: Assertion Failed
```

when the test method is modified as

```
apvA.hasError = null; 
       System.assert(apvA.hasError == null);
```

but coverage is attained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you're covering the setter only by setting value to that variable. Try retrieve the value:

```
Boolean testError = apvA.hasError;
System.assert(testError == false);
```

Comment: System.AssertException: Assertion Failed - error is thrown while i run the test class

Comment: I can't see the rest of your code, but this is how you should solve your problem

Comment: the error is in the System.assert(testError == false); statement... is there any other way